# cucumber + selenium + rcov =?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, rcov

Is it possible to measure coverage using selenium-driven features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Rails plugin named [Mainline](http://github.com/gaffo/mainline) which could be the "glue" you're looking for to get cucumber + selenium/watir + rcov working together.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a rake task for it or are you running your own hand baked commands?

If you could provide more information we'll see what we can come up with.